# Rails validation exclusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have created a validation on a table but want to exclude the validation on a specific column in my controller create method. How would I go about doing this?

```
def validate_cookie_brand
 render json: 422, unless valid_cookie_brand?
end

def valid_cookie_brand?
  CookieBrand.exists?(cookie_brand: cookie_create_request_params[:cookie_brand]))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It will not be the whole solution but few things which you should keep in mind

you should respond in your action whenever cookie brand is valid or not.
secondly, probably you are trying to enforce 422 HTTP status, not 422 as the response body.
thirdly, one should not separate unless condition from execution by ','

code with all cautions above fixed:

`def validate_cookie_brand
   if valid_cookie_brand?
     render json: { message: 'valid cookie' } # status is by default 200
   else
     render json: { message: 'invalid cookie brand' }, status: 422 
   end
end`